# LinkedList length, access and implementation via a heap. C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, nodes

I am trying to print the length of a linked list I created in another .c file called linklist.c from the main.c file. It is not working and I believe is has something to do with pointers and/or memory management over all. I call into question the heap mainly here. some guidance would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    struct node* mylist = BuildOneTwoThree();
    int length = Length(mylist);

    printf(mylist->data);
    printf(length);
    return 0;
}

#include "node.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Return the number of nodes in a list (while-loop version)
int Length(struct node** head) {
   int count = 0;
   struct node* current = head;
   while (current != NULL) {
      count++;
      current = current->next;
   }
   return(count);
}

/*
 Build the list {1, 2, 3} in the heap and store
 its head pointer in a local stack variable.
 Returns the head pointer to the caller.
*/
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
   struct node* head = NULL;
   struct node* second = NULL;
   struct node* third = NULL;
   head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
   second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   head->data = 1; // setup first node
   head->next = second; // note: pointer assignment rule
   second->data = 2; // setup second node
   second->next = third;
   third->data = 3; // setup third link
   third->next = NULL;
   // At this point, the linked list referenced by "head"
   // matches the list in the drawing.
   return head;
}

/*
 Takes a list and a data value.
 Creates a new link with the given data and pushes
 it onto the front of the list.
 The list is not passed in by its head pointer.
 Instead the list is passed in as a "reference" pointer
 to the head pointer -- this allows us
 to modify the caller's memory.
*/
void Push(struct node** headRef, int data) {
   struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = *headRef; // The '*' to dereferences back to the real head
   *headRef = newNode; // ditto head points to new node
}

// Given a list and an index, return the data
// in the nth node of the list. The nodes are numbered from 0.
// Assert fails if the index is invalid (outside 0..lengh-1).
int GetNth(struct node* head, int index) {
    struct node* current = head;
    int answer = 0;
    int x = index;
    if(x <= 0 || x >= sizeof(head)-1 )
        {
            return -1;
        }
    for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(head)-1; i++){
        if (i == x){
            return current->data;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

As you can see I use the BuildOneTwoThree function to build the linkedlist and am writing appropriate functions...It crashes when I try to access mylist into output.

Comment: What do you think `sizeof(head)` will be?

Comment: Your `Length` function declares its parameter to be a `struct node **`, but then uses it as if it were a `struct node *`.  You should fix this, but it is probably not the source of the problem, because the actual argument matches the function's implementation rather than its declaration.

Comment: Yes I saw I changed it back to struct node*. That was from previous troubleshooting in which I thought the error was me trying to pass a pointer to a pointer. @JohnBollinger

Comment: sizeof(head)?  I am assuming the size in bytes of the pointer head (or what it points to) @joop

Comment: `printf()` takes a format string as its first argument.  You are instead passing plain `int`s.  The resulting behavior is undefined, and in practice is highly unlikely to be what you wanted..

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(head)-1; i++){
        if (i == x){
            return current->data;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }` seems to assume that sizeof(head) yields the number of elements in the LL?

Comment: It looks like it does, @joop, and such an assumption is likely to be erroneous, but that function is not actually called in the OP's example program.

Comment: @TevinCarter, when I fix your `printf` calls by inserting an appropriate format string, your program runs cleanly for me and produces the output I expect.

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming it had to do with C and the printf function as well but to a lesser extent. I studied C briefly in the past and forgot about the printf function's formats.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: Yes, this is all very new to me. I will keep this in mind. I guess I use and only know of GDB as a debugger. I am currently on a windows machine and use code::blocks to code and use linux on my laptop and vim to code.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part the code seems to function from the point of view of the question only, printf had to be properly formatted.

```
printf("%i", length);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. type cast malloc required
2. Change **head to *head in function argument Length
3. Use proper printf statement.

This question is limited to printing lenght of link list. please find code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* BuildOneTwoThree();
int Length(struct node* head);
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    struct node* mylist = BuildOneTwoThree();
    int length = Length(mylist);

    printf("data =%d\n",mylist->data);
    printf("length = %d",length);
    return 0;
}


// Return the number of nodes in a list (while-loop version)
int Length(struct node* head) {
   int count = 0;
   struct node* current = head;
   while (current != NULL) {
      count++;
      current = current->next;
   }
   return(count);
}

/*
 Build the list {1, 2, 3} in the heap and store
 its head pointer in a local stack variable.
 Returns the head pointer to the caller.
*/
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
   struct node* head = NULL;
   struct node* second = NULL;
   struct node* third = NULL;

   head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // allocate 3 nodes in the heap
   second = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   third = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   head->data = 1; // setup first node
   head->next = second; // note: pointer assignment rule
   second->data = 2; // setup second node
   second->next = third;
   third->data = 3; // setup third link
   third->next = NULL;
   // At this point, the linked list referenced by "head"
   // matches the list in the drawing.
   return head;
}
```

Comment: There should be no type cast with malloc in C (it is needed in C++, if you need to use malloc from C++ for some special, explicit reason).